# Combine php functions in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the below code

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

and it displays the description of a coupon for my site,

I want to add the name of each store at the end, using the following code

```
at <?php echo appthemes_get_custom_taxonomy($post->ID, APP_TAX_STORE, 'name'); ?>
```

so for example it will say............20% off clothing at 6pm.com.

As of now when I add code it separates and creates a new paragraph like below.........

20% off clothing.

at 6pm.com.

How do I combine this as one sentence.

Here is entire coupon function

```
    <!-- #coupon-main -->

                        </div> <!-- #head-box -->

                        <div class="box-bottom">&nbsp;</div>

                        <div class="text-box">


                            <?php appthemes_before_post_content(); ?>

                            <?php the_content(); ?>

                            <?php clpr_edit_coupon_link(); ?>

                            <?php clpr_reset_coupon_votes_link(); ?>

                            <?php appthemes_after_post_content(); ?> 

                        </div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803882/how-to-combine-php-arrays hmm...

Comment: You know, if you really want help, you'd start answering some of the questions that came from your other posts

Comment: I have explained and rephrased question, I tried preg replace and it gave me error

Comment: Learn PHP. We can't hold your hand and help you fix all the problems that pop up.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress is likely adding a `<p></p>` around your content inside of the editor, which is getting saved in the content of the post. You can use `get_the_content()` and check to see if it ends with a `</p>`, and if it does, remove it, `echo` the name of the store, and then re-add the `</p>` after that.

```
<?php

$content = trim(get_the_content());
if(substr($content, -4) == '</p>') {
    echo substr($content, 0, -4);
    echo appthemes_get_custom_taxonomy($post->ID, APP_TAX_STORE, 'name');
    echo '</p>';
}
else{
    echo $content, appthemes_get_custom_taxonomy($post->ID, APP_TAX_STORE, 'name');
}
```

Comment: Is there a `<div`> after it then? That won't move (likely) move down unless your content is surrounded by `<p></p>` or `<div></div>`

Comment: I added more info to question and there is a </div> at end of class like above

Comment: I added ?> to end and it now combines sentence, however it is no space after like........... Save up to 80% off Reebok.6pm , how can i add space using this function and the question will be answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$content = trim(get_the_content());
if(substr($content, -4) == '</p>') {
echo substr($content, 0, -4);
echo appthemes_get_custom_taxonomy($post->ID, APP_TAX_STORE, 'name');
echo '</p>';
}
else{
$content = preg_replace("/\.$/"," ",$content);
echo $content, appthemes_get_custom_taxonomy($post->ID, APP_TAX_STORE, 'name');
} ?>
```